# binding validation controls in a datagrid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-controls

I have the following datagrid:

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="gastosReembolsables" ShowFooter="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="DATAitem2"></AlternatingItemStyle>
        <ItemStyle CssClass="DATAitem1"></ItemStyle>
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="DATAheader"></HeaderStyle>
        <FooterStyle CssClass="DATAitem1"></FooterStyle>
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateColumn runat="server" HeaderText="Item">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Item" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("item") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Item" Width="40px" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>
            <asp:TemplateColumn runat="server" HeaderText="Precio">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="precio" Width="40px" Text='<%# Eval("precio") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="40px" ID="precio"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>
            <asp:TemplateColumn runat="server" HeaderText="Cantidad">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="cantidad" Width="40px" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cantidad") %>' />
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="unidadMedida" DataValueField='id' DataTextField="nombre"></asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="cantidad" Width="40px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="unidadMedida" DataValueField='id' DataTextField="nombre"></asp:DropDownList>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn runat="server" HeaderText="Total" DataField="total" />
            <asp:BoundColumn runat="server" Visible="False" DataField="id" />
            <asp:TemplateColumn runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="actualizarGasto" runat="server" CommandName="Update" ImageUrl="../../imagenes/btn_guardar.gif"
                        CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="item" />
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="eliminarGasto" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" ImageUrl="../../imagenes/btn_eliminar.gif"
                        CausesValidation="False" ValidationGroup="item" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="agregarGasto" runat="server" CommandName="New" ImageUrl="../../imagenes/agregar.png"
                        CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="footer" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>
            <asp:TemplateColumn runat="server" Visible="True">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="validaCantidad" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="cantidad" ValidationGroup='item<%# Eval("id") %>' ErrorMessage="Ingrese una Cantidad" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="validaCantidadNumerico" Display="Dynamic" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="cantidad" ValidationGroup='item<%# Eval("id") %>' ErrorMessage="La cantidad debe ser num&eacute;rica" 
                        Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Integer"></asp:CompareValidator>
                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="validaUnidadMedida" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="unidadMedida" ValidationGroup='item<%# Eval("id") %>' ErrorMessage="Seleccione una unidad de medida" Display="Dynamic" Operator="NotEqual" ValueToCompare="0"></asp:CompareValidator>
                    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="resumenGastosReembolsablesItem" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="True" ShowSummary="false" ValidationGroup='item<%# Eval("id") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="validaCantidad" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="cantidad" ErrorMessage="Ingrese una Cantidad" Display="None" ValidationGroup="footer"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="validaCantidadNumerico" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="cantidad" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="La cantidad debe ser num&eacute;rica" 
                        Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Integer" ValidationGroup="footer"></asp:CompareValidator>
                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="validaUnidadMedida" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="unidadMedida" ErrorMessage="Seleccione una unidad de medida" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="footer" Operator="NotEqual" ValueToCompare="0"></asp:CompareValidator>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="validaItem" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="Item" ErrorMessage="Ingrese un Item" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="footer"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="validaPrecio" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="precio" ErrorMessage="Ingrese un precio" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="footer"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="validaPrecioNumerico" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="precio" ErrorMessage="El precio debe ser num&eacute;rico" 
                        Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Double" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="footer"></asp:CompareValidator>
                    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="resumenGastosReembolsablesFooter" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="True" ShowSummary="False" ValidationGroup="footer" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>
        </Columns>
    </asp:DataGrid>
```

all bindings work except the ones in the validation controls for the itemtemplate of the last column (they are passed as text to the web page).

Why is this happening? is it even possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use the `<%# ... %>` syntax to specify the *entire* value of a property, not a partial value.

Change

```
ValidationGroup='item<%# Eval("id") %>'
```

to

```
ValidationGroup='<%# "item" & Eval("id") %>'
```